# Creating a webtrend function to remove duplication using js apply and call

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I re-factor the code to remove duplication and create a common method ?

```
(function(){

    $("#a", "#main").bind("mouseover", function(){
              var id1 = $("#one").text(),
                  args = ["DCSext.common1","common1","DCSext.common2","DCSext.title","one", "DCSext.ti", id1];

              dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
     });

    $("#b", "#cool").bind("click", function(){
           var id2 = $("#two").text(),
               args = ["DCSext.common1","common1","DCSext.common2","DCSext.title", "two", "DCSext.some", id2];
               dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
    });

    $("body").delegate("a", "click", function(){
         var id3 = $("#three").text(),
               args = ["DCSext.common1","common1","DCSext.common2","DCSext.new", "what", "DCSext.where", "us"];
               dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
    });

    }());
```

I have some common logs which are almost repeated in all callbacks. I can use a variable like

```
var commonlogs = ["DCSext.common1","common1","DCSext.common2","common2", "DCSext.common3", "common3" ];
```

i can use `commonlogs.push("DCSext.title","one","DCSext.ti", "two").` But not finding a proper way to re-factoring repeating the DCSext stuff again and again since its very granular level .

Thanks for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: @paul Can you clarify your problem? I don't understand what you mean by "common logs". Are you referring to the `args` array you're passing into `dcsMultitrack()`? The `commonlogs` array you posted includes some strings that aren't in any of the above `args` arrays.

Comment: @seand purpose of including commonlogs variable is to move out repeated strings from the existing arrays in callback function .If you see my top code mostly ["DCSext.common1","common1","DCSext.common2"] been repeated almost in all callback function .So I can extract into an variable and can just do commonlogs.push(extra strings) but i do not think it i san elegent solution .So looking for some other advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can do,
the only thing I would suggest is to use `concat` instead of `push`, this way you can keep re-using `commonLogs`, and maybe have 1 `commonLogs` per group.

So

```
  var commonLogs = [ [] ];
  commonLogs[1]  = ["DCSext.common1","common1"];
  commonLogs[2]  = commonLogs[1].concat( ["DCSext.common2","common2"] );
  commonLogs[3]  = commonLogs[2].concat( ["DCSext.common3","common3"] );
```

Then you can

```
(function(){

  $("#a", "#main").bind("mouseover", function(){
          var id1 = $("#one").text(),
              args = commonLogs[2].concat( ["DCSext.title","one", "DCSext.ti", id1] );
          dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
  });

  $("#b", "#cool").bind("click", function(){
       var id2 = $("#two").text(),
           args = commonLogs[2].concat( ["DCSext.title", "two", "DCSext.some", id2] );
       dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
  });

  $("body").delegate("a", "click", function(){
     var args = commonLogs[2].concat( ["DCSext.new", "what", "DCSext.where", "us"] );
     dcsMultitrack.apply(this, args);
  });

}());
```